# Cant locate image on pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hey i am trying to locate an image but get this error on why i use the value as (any,any,250,250) but doesnt show the error when i use(any,any,350(more than 350),250(more than 250))

here is my code

```
`
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import cv2
import numpy as np

PlayerOnRight = False
PlayerOnFullRight = False
PlayerOnFullLeft = False
PlayerOnLeft = False
PlayerOnMiddle = False

while 1:
    if PlayerOnMiddle == True and pyautogui.locateOnScreen('player.png', region=(1080,600,800,200), confidence=0.7) != None:
        print("Right Side")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('player.png', region=(825,800,250,250), confidence=0.3) !=None:
        print("Left Side")
        time.sleep(0.5)

`
here is the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pyhton_bot\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('player.png', region=(825,800,250,250), confidence=0.3) !=None:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 353, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 219, in _locateAll_opencv
    raise ValueError('needle dimension(s) exceed the haystack image or region dimensions')
ValueError: needle dimension(s) exceed the haystack image or region dimensions

`


i expted it to work noramlly to locate image and pint the given text but got this error

please help me fix this
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the region has to be bigger than your player.png image. Either crop your player.png image or increase the region size